# Вывод данных в виде таблицы в консоле

Tags: c++

как мне это вывести  таблицей в консоле?

```
os << dt.year << "." << dt.month << '/' << dt.day << dt.name << dt.surname << dt.discplace << dt.wayplace << endl;  
    return os;
```

Comment: а вы берите и прочитайте о возможностьях класса std::ostream, а также манипуляторы - такие как  std::setw....

Comment: а если устанешь от этого нечитаемого сверхдлинного безумия и захочется адекватной строки форматирования в стиле С или питона, то сочувствую, в стандарте этого нет; и едва ли ни единственным выходом останется `boost::format`. Если зависимость от boost'а — не выриант, то проще будет использовать обычный C'шный `*printf()`.

Comment: @Fat-Zer Ну почему же "в стандарте нет"? `printf` - вполне стандартная для C++ библиотечная функция...

Comment: @Harry, пока меня не побили камнями, молю о прощении за упоминание священного Стандарта в суе ;)

Comment: @Fat-Zer Не камнями, а монолитными структурами :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подключаете библиотеку iomanip и выводите

```
cout << setw(8) << dt.year << "|" << setw(6) << dt.month << "|" и т.д
```

setw() задает сколько места будет выделятся под вывод значения